# All subsets from a set in python recursively (Nonetype error)

Tags: python, recursion, subset, nonetype

I am trying to get all subsets from a set recursively, here is the code I have so far:

```
aset = [1,2,10,4,5,99]

def subSets(aset):
    if len(aset) == 0:
        return []
    prevSets = subSets(aset[:len(aset)-1])
    newSets =[]
    print prevSets
    for s in prevSets:
        newSets.append(s.append(aset[-1]))
    return prevSets.extend(newSets)

print subSets(aset)
```

With this python implementation I am getting the following error and I can't seem to wrap my head around why:

```
  File "9_4.py", line 9, in subSets
    for s in prevSets:
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

It seems that `None` has made its way into `prevSet`, but I cannot figure out why, any ideas?

**EDIT - Proper Solution:**

Thanks to Martijn Pieters I figured out exactly what was wrong, ultimately I was trying to achieve the following:

```
def subSets(aset):
    if len(aset) == 0:
        return [[]]
    prevSets = subSets(aset[:-1])
    newSets =[]
    for s in prevSets:
        another = s + [aset[-1]]
        newSets.append(another)
    return prevSets + newSets

print subSets(aset)
```

Comment: Niggle: Those are lists, not sets.

Comment: @dawg A set in the mathematical sense. I implemented them as lists.

Comment: Enter `print aset` at the top of the function. You will see that your loop is never executed. Then at the bottom, you  have `return prevSets.extend(newSets)` which returns `None`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`prevSets` is set to `None` here:

```
prevSets = subSets(aset[:len(aset)-1])
```

because the following line produces `None`:

```
return prevSets.extend(newSets)
```

`list.extend()` alters the list *in-place* and returns `None`. Separate the call and return:

```
prevSets.extend(newSets)
return prevSets
```

or use concatenation instead:

```
return prevSets + newSets
```

Note that you make a similar mistake elsewhere:

```
for s in prevSets:
    newSets.append(s.append(aset[-1]))
```

`list.append()` also returns `None`, so you are in essence adding `None` to `newSets` there. I'm not sure what you wanted to append there exactly; if you wanted to add `s` to `newSets` after adding `aset[-1]` to `s`, do so on separate lines:

```
for s in prevSets:
    s.append(aset[-1])
    newSets.append(s)
```